# After install of Laravel in Ubuntu on enter command php artisan ser failed to open stream:

Tags: laravel

php artisan ser
PHP Warning:  require(/home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/vendor/autoload.php): [failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/artisan on line 18](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yeLWL.jpg)
PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /home/ritesh/Desktop/blog/artisan on line 18